# Asymptotic Proof

Tags: big-o

Assume f1(n) is O(g1(n)) and f2(n) is O(g2(n)), show that f1(n)/f2(n) is not O(g1(n)/g2(n).
I have actually worked this out to 
F1/f2=c1/c2
But how does this show they are not equal. I am having a problem with that

Answer (score 0):

It is not true, that `f1/f2 = c1/c2`. As a hint, if you want to prove it is not true, it is enough to show counterexample. Think of when division can make result bigger than the thing we devide.